# How do you create an indexable empty list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a way to neatly create large (i.e. indexable) empty lists in python?

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
firstgen=G.neighbors(node1)
secgen=[]
thirdgen=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]  #11 brackets because len(secgen)=11

for i in firstgen:
    secgen.append(G.neighbors(i))   

for i in range(len(secgen)):
    for j in secgen[i]:
        thirdgen[i].append(G.neighbors(j))
```

What I am doing is finding the neighbors of the neighbors of the neighbors of an original node in a network and so my third generation list of neighbors should have the structure [ [[...],[...],[...]] , [[...],[...],[...]] , [[...],[...],[...]] ] but I am new to python and have not been able to find how to make this work without manually putting in the length of `thirdgen`.

Sorry for the confusing explanation. I am doing this in order to find triads in the network i.e. if any of the third gen nodes are the same as the initial node then I have found a triad.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just realised that I can simply put `thirdgen.append([])` in the first loop. Still curious about other methods though.

Comment: This looks like it could get ugly. Unless you need to do it this way for reasons unknown to me, I would suggest making your own data structure for this, one with methods to handle your specific needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Indexing into a container is what you do to retrieve an element. Normal definitions of "empty" don't allow for the possibility that there actually is an element there to retrieve. It looks like you want a nested list of empty lists; but *what are you going to do with it*? Please explain much, much more carefully what you are talking about with "networks" and "triads".

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create the empty lists. You can use list comprehensions to build your nested lists:

```
firstgen = G.neighbors(node1)
secndgen = [G.neighbors(node) for node in firstgen]
thirdgen = [[G.neighbors(node) for node in group] for group in secndgen]
```

- `firstgen: [node, ...]`
- `secndgen: [[node, ...], ...]`
- `thirdgen: [[[node, ...], ...], ...]`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
thirdgen = [list() for x in range(len(secgen))]
thirdgen = [list() for x in range(11)]
```

Or I might be misunderstanding the actual question.

Comment: `list()` is more idiomatically spelled `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use list generator as follows: `[[] for x in range(11)]`.

Comment: That is a list comprehension. A generator would be `([] for x in xrange(11))`